Monogame My 3D objects overlap instead of drawing based on position relative to the camera
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWImAT-g7tE
Hey, I’m having trouble with overlapping 3d objects. My 3D rendered models/objects are drawn on top of each other based on which draw method gets called last instead of basing it off the pixel’s position relative to the camera. Depth buffering is supposed to solve this issue on it's own.. but it doesn't
I was told that either my “depth read” or “depth write” are failing. My “Depth read” is I assume setting the DepthStencilState to default:
            graphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;

And the depth write is this right:
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.Black, 1.0f, 0);

I’ve tried everything. Even removing the spritebatch because that has some effect on the buffering and rendering. My only theory left is that I keep resetting the graphicsDevice Vertexbuffer by this line of code
                graphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(shape.vertexBuffer);

But ChatGPT informed me that isn’t a problem. Does anyone have an idea where my problem could possible be? Here is how I draw my 3D objects:
    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
            graphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
            graphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque; // Spritebatch sets it default to AlphaBlend

            base.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
            Draw3DModels();
            Draw3DShapes();
        }

        private void Draw3DModels() {
            foreach (ThreeDGameObject threeDGameObject in ThreeDObjects) {
                Model model = threeDGameObject.model;
                foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes) {
                    foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects) {

                        // Transformations
                        Matrix worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(threeDGameObject.Position) *
                            Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(threeDGameObject.Rotation.Y, threeDGameObject.Rotation.X, threeDGameObject.Rotation.Z);
                        effect.World = worldMatrix;
                        effect.View = camera.View;
                        effect.Projection = camera.Projection;

                        // Light
                        // effect.AmbientLightColor = new Vector3(1f, 0, 0);
                        // effect.EnableDefaultLighting();

                        // Other shader settings
                        effect.TextureEnabled = true;
                        effect.Alpha = threeDGameObject.Alpha;

                        effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
                    }

                    mesh.Draw();
                }
            }
        }

        private void Draw3DShapes() {
            basicEffect.Projection = camera.Projection;
            basicEffect.View = camera.View;
            basicEffect.World = camera.World;

            // Draw all shapes
            foreach (Shape shape in shapes) { 
                // Transformations
                Matrix worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(shape.Position) *
                    Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(shape.Rotation.Y, shape.Rotation.X, shape.Rotation.Z);
                basicEffect.World = worldMatrix;

                graphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(shape.vertexBuffer);
                graphicsDevice.Indices = shape.indexBuffer;

                foreach (EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes) { 
                    pass.Apply();
                    graphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, shape.vertices.Length / 3);
                }
            }
        }

Could the problem be in the camera?
I am in Visual Studio Code
Monogame version: 3.8.1.303
GameEnvironment class:
    public GameEnvironment() {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferFormat = SurfaceFormat.Color;
        graphics.PreferredDepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();


        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        inputHelper = new InputHelper();
        gameStateManager = new GameStateManager();
        spriteScale = Matrix.CreateScale(1, 1, 1);
        random = new Random();
        assetManager = new AssetManager(Content);
        gameSettingsManager = new GameSettingsManager();
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.Black, 1.0f, 0);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null, spriteScale);
        gameStateManager.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }


GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;

is the correct setting to enable writing into and reading from the depth buffer.
You also need to make sure that your backbuffer (the main target framebuffer) has a depth buffer applied to it. Something like this, where you set up your GraphicsDeviceManager and backbuffer on app start (either the constructor of your inherited Game class or the Initialize() function of it):
DeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferFormat = SurfaceFormat.Color;
DeviceManager.PreferredDepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8;

There are several possible settings for the depth buffer but any except 'None' should work.
It is also a good idea to place this line
base.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);

at the end of the function or at the start (e.g. if you only draw UI with SpriteBatch, then more likely at the end) Let me know if it helped!
Small addition:
And the depth write is this right:
```cs
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.Black, 1.0f, 0);

This is the clearing of both, the color buffer and the depth buffer, i.e. drawing the background color, and clearing any depth data from the last frame.
Edit for comment:
I assume, 'gameStateManager.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch)' is the called function above in your code. AFAIK, 3D-Models should not be drawn inside of a SpriteBatch Begin() End() block as graphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(...); is actually a different kind of draw call. SpriteBatch defers the rendering to render things in one batch while DrawPrimitives(...) does not.  pass.Apply(); and graphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(...) and similar drawing functions interfere with SpriteBatch's drawing block (everything between spriteBatch.Begin(...) and spriteBatch.End()).
Try something like this:
 protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.Black, 1.0f, 0);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null, spriteScale);
        // Here, you only draw 2Dish stuff like UI or sprites which should be depth sorted via their position
        gameStateManager.DrawSprites(gameTime, spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();
        // Then after (or before that) draw your 3D models and shapes in an extra function (no base.Draw(...) in there though!)
        gameStateManager.Draw3DModels(gameTime, spriteBatch);
    }

Important is that you draw your 3D models/shapes not from within an active SpriteBatch Begin() End() block.

Thanks for the reply and small additions for my code. It still doesn't work though, Am I applying the depth buffer correctly? I edited my post at the end to add parts of my game environment class

I edited my answer accordingly, please let me know if you have any more questions!

Hey, that doesn't work either :/. The spritebatch does interfere a lot with the graphics device, however I found this website which basically tells you that setting the blendstate and depthstencilstate should just fix everything. https://web.archive.org/web/20151006083852/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments
As long as I set this before drawing the 3D objects I shouldn't have a problem with the spritebatch. I'm now contemplating writing my own code for drawing pixels based on the depth buffer

Yeah that idea was way too optimistic lol. Looping through the screen and drawing the pixels myself based on the depth is wayyyyy too cost intensive
I'll try to follow a step by step tutorial for a 3D world copying the exact same code and see if that gets me anywhere

Yeah no that would be heavy. The tutorial idea seems reasonable as I (at least at the moment) can't further infer the cause of the problem from here. I wish you all the best on your journey!

If anyone else got this problem, create and set your viewport only in the initializer of your game class, doing this anywhere else will break your depth buffer, even if you set the DepthStencilState back to default every frame.
        Viewport viewport = new Viewport();
        viewport.X = (graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2) - (screenWidth / 2);
        viewport.Y = (graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / 2) - (screenHeight / 2);
        viewport.Width = screenWidth;
        viewport.Height = screenHeight;
        GraphicsDevice.Viewport = viewport;


